# Describe max instances for a service in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I do a lot of testing and frequently find out that the AWS ECS prod services are not the same as the test services. Specifically the Auto Scaling Minimum and Maximum tasks are frequently incorrect in test as some well meaning devops decreases them to save money.

I want to use the AWS CLI to grab these details from each (I have read only in both prod and test) and automate the compare prior to the test run.

I have tried both describe-clusters and describe-services but neither seem to give me the maximum tasks. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The ECS autoscalling is managed by [Application Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/what-is-application-auto-scaling.html).

Subsequently, to get `MaxCapacity` and `MinCapacity` one has to use `application-autoscaling` API:

- [describe-scalable-targets](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/application-autoscaling/describe-scalable-targets.html)

For ECS, the `resource-ids` parameter is:

> The resource type is service and the unique identifier is the **cluster** name and **service** name. Example: service/default/sample-webapp

The command's output will contain `MaxCapacity` and `MinCapacity`. For example, for ECS:

```
{
    "ScalableTargets": [
        {
            "ScalableDimension": "ecs:service:DesiredCount",
            "ResourceId": "service/default/web-app",
            "RoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ApplicationAutoscalingECSRole",
            "SuspendedState": {
                "DynamicScalingOutSuspended": false,
                "ScheduledScalingSuspended": false,
                "DynamicScalingInSuspended": false
            },
            "CreationTime": 1462558906.199,
            "MinCapacity": 1,
            "ServiceNamespace": "ecs",
            "MaxCapacity": 10
        }
    ]
}
```